# java Get hashmap keys as integer array

Tags: java, integer, hashmap

I have a hashmap like this

```
public HashMap <String,People> valueHashMap  = new Hashmap();
```

Here the key to my HashMap is time in seconds as string, ie I am adding value to hashmap like this

```
long timeSinceEpoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
valueHashMap.put(
                   Integer.toString((int)timeSinceEpoch)
                   , people_obj
                );
```

Now I want to get all keys in the hashmap into an array list of integer.

```
ArrayList<Integer> intKeys = valueHashMap.keys()...
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why are you converting int to String before putting it in the Map?

Comment: @Sanjay T. Sharma can java hashmap take integer keys?

Comment: Yes if you define it as Map<Integer, People>.

Comment: It can take Integer keys (but not int keys).

Comment: Yes, integers are perfectly fine for being used as keys in a Map. It's just that you will be putting an `Integer` instead of the primitive `int` in the `Map` but I don't think that should be a problem for you. Also, auto-boxing will help you cut down the conversion from `int` to `Integer` call.

Comment: Well it seems a total misunderstanding on my part...As you guys pointed out java hashmap can certainly take non string keys..I was touching my nose in a wrong way..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no direct way of converting a list of `String`s to a list of `Integer`s:

1. Either you need to redefine your `valueHashMap` like this:

   ```
   public HashMap<Integer, People> valueHashMap  = new HashMap<Integer, People>();

   ....

   ArrayList<Integer> intKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>(valueHashMap.keySet());
   ```
2. Or you need to loop:

   ```
   ArrayList<Integer> intKeys = new ArraList<Integer>();

   for (String stringKey : valueHashMap.keySet())
        intKeys.add(Integer.parseInt(stringKey);
   ```
3. **I would advice you however to use the `Long` as key instead**:

   ```
   public HashMap<Long, People> valueHashMap  = new HashMap<Long, People>();
   ```

   then there would be no casting to `int` *(and you can use (1) above with `Long` instead)*.

Comment: +1 using `Long` will help avoid [the Year 2038 Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: There are some mistakes in option 2

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a List of one type to a List of another type, so you have to iterate through the keys and parse each one.

```
for(String k : valueHashMap.keySet()) {
    intKeys.add(Integer.valueOf(k));
}
```

Comment: That's *parsing* and not *casting*!

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: That's because my answer covered the general case (where you can sometimes cast) and my code was for this specific instance of the problem. Fixed it anyway to avoid confusion.

Comment: the problem is that many people call *any* kind of type conversion "casting" and that is wrong and confuses people even further.

Answer (score 0):

You really have type problems. Why do you change the longs into Strings to store them in a map. Why not simply use Long, which needs less memory and is more descriptive. Then why use Integer.toString to transform a long into a String? By casting your long to an int, you risk loosing information by. Here's how the code should probably look like:

```
private Map<Long, People> valueHashMap = new Hashmap<Long, People>();

long timeSinceEpoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
valueHashMap.put(timeSinceEpoch, people_obj);
List<Long> longKeys = new ArrayList<Long>(valueHashMap.keySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer` class for that as follows.

```
List<Integer> intKeys  = (List<Integer>)CollectionUtils.collect(valueHashMap.keySet(), new Transformer() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Object transform(Object key) {
                                        return Integer.valueOf(key);
                                    }
                                }, new ArrayList<Integer>());
```